# Android Studio Emulator no more considering Swipes on Notebook Touchscreens as Input

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, touchscreen, android-studio-bumblebee

I upgraded to Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 and realized that I cannot fully control the emulator with the touchscreen of my notebook anymore. Press events on the touchscreen (like mouse clicks) are still recognized correctly, but when I swipe nothing happens in the emulator.

Unfortunately, I did not note down the previous version of Android Studio that I had installed before, but with previous Android Studio versions I was always able to fully control the Android emulator via the touchscreen (as if I was actually testing my app on a real mobile phone).

My Google searches did not show any results related to this issue. Does anyone have an idea what the root cause could be and if it is possible to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling *launch in tool window* in Settings::Tools::Emulator fixed it for me (requires emulator restart to take effect).

Credits to [YuriBlaise on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidStudio/comments/t4bntz/emulator_doesnt_work_properly_anymore/)